# Setting grid columns css

Tags: html, css

I need all grid columns to shrink together when the browser size changes(example: 1920:1080 => 1200:900), and not the right one first, and then all the others. Examples of incorrect operation in the screenshots

[image]
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 30vmin 90vmin 30vmin;
      grid-template-rows: 30vmin 30vmin 30vmin;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .item{
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="item item_1">1</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_3">3</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you required to use `vmin` as unit? If not, you could use `vw` as unit for the `grid-template-columns`. Make sure it's not exceeding a total of 100. An alternative would be to use [`fr` as unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#the_fr_unit).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `fr` in the `grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;` to keep your size ratios which will shrink and grow together. also remove `justify-content: space-between;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 30vmin 30vmin 30vmin;
    }
    
    .item{
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="item item_1">1</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_3">3</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```